# How to combine multiple strings in a single captured group

Tags: .net, regex

The users of our software need to import their existing data into our database.  As they all have different text files structures, I'm using regex (.NET) as part of a universal import routine to extract datafields from their text files and import them in the correct fields in our database.

Simply by adapting the regex "pattern" via a configuration-setting I was able to adapt to whatever importfile format the customer came up with.

For example: to import "Id" and "Name".

```
Text file:
==========
Id      Name            Code
0001    Tractor         TRA
0020    Truck           TRU
0021    Bulldozer       BDZ
0022    PickupTruck     PKT


Import routine
==============
pattern = "^(?<Id>\d{4})[ ]*(?<Naam>.{16}).*[\r\n]*$"
For Each oMatch As Match In Regex.Matches(FileContent, pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline)
    dataTableMachines.AddMachineRow(New Guid(oMatch.Groups("Id").Value.Trim.PadLeft(32, "0"c)),
                                    oMatch.Groups("MachineName").Value.Trim)
Next
```

However I'm stuck now with a customer who wants the "imported MachineName" to be a combination of "Code" + " " + "Name".
So for the first row the captured group "MachineName" should contain "TRA Tractor".

How to accomplish this by simply adapting the regex pattern in the above import routine ?

If not possible, any recommended solution that avoids hardcoding a separate build for each customer ?

Comment: By adapting the regex to match backwards? Isn't it easier to adapt the code?

Comment: Use [`^(?<Id>\d{4})[ ]*(?<Naam>.{16})(?<Code>.*)\r*$`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%28%3f%3cId%3e%5cd%7b4%7d%29%5b+%5d*%28%3f%3cNaam%3e.%7b16%7d%29%28%3f%3ccode%3e.*%29%5cr*%24&i=Id++++++Name++++++++++++Code%0d%0a0001++++Tractor+++++++++TRA%0d%0a0020++++Truck+++++++++++TRU%0d%0a0021++++Bulldozer+++++++BDZ%0d%0a0022++++PickupTruck+++++PKT&o=m) and build the output with the language means.

Comment: @WiktorStribizew  "Building the output with the language means" is technically very well possible, but that means that I need a different codebase for every customer.  I'm looking for a solution where I can adapt to different textfile formats by only changing the regex pattern which the software reads from a config-file.

Comment: You cannot capture discontinuous texts into 1 capturing group - it is not how regex works.